# Trying to load kernal32 and J# library from C# (.NET 4.0) and getting kernal32 load errors

Tags: c#, .net, dllimport

I'm creating an application in C# using Visual Studio 2010/.NET 4.0.  For part of the application I need to zip the files and make use of the J# library.  I'm having an issue importing kernal32.dll.  I've tried setting the import value to "kernal32", "kernal32.dll" and the absolute path in the system32 folder.  The error I get is below and the relevant source code is below that.  The error occurs at the line where I invoke "LoadLibrary(fullPath);"  Any help would be greatly excavated!

I pulled some of this code from an example at http://blogs.windwardreports.com/davidt/2011/02/calling-j-code-from-net-40.html

> System.DllNotFoundException was unhandled
>     Message=Unable to load DLL 'kernal32': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
>     Source=ZipLibrary
>     TypeName=""
>     StackTrace:
>          at ZipLibrary.Zipper.LoadLibrary(String ipFileName)
>          at ZipLibrary.Zipper..ctor(String directoryToZip, String zipToPath) in c:\users\cchamberlain\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\AppDeploy\ZipLibrary\Zipper.cs:line 37
>          at AppDeployLibrary.AppDeployer.Deploy() in c:\users\cchamberlain\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\AppDeploy\AppDeployLibrary\AppDeployer.cs:line 37
>          at AppDeploy.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\users\cchamberlain\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\AppDeploy\AppDeploy\Program.cs:line 21
>          at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>          at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
>     InnerException:

```
public class Zipper
{
    private const string DotNetFrameworkRelativePath = @"..\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727";
    private const string VjsDllName = "vjsnativ.dll";

    [DllImport("kernal32", SetLastError=true)]
    static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string ipFileName);

    private readonly string _directoryToZip;
    private readonly string _zipToPath;

    public Zipper(string directoryToZip, string zipToPath)
    {
        // If the current framework is .NET 4, include the VJS dll.)))
        if(Environment.Version.Major >= 4)
        {
            string folder = SystemIO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System), DotNetFrameworkRelativePath);
            folder = SystemIO.Path.GetFullPath(folder);
            string fullPath = SystemIO.Path.Combine(folder, VjsDllName);

            // Check to see if file exists, if not the J# redistributable is not installed.
            if(!SystemIO.File.Exists(fullPath))
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("ERROR: Zipper requires that the Microsoft Visual J#® 2.0 Redistributable Package be installed on the environment.");
            }

            LoadLibrary(fullPath);
        }

        _directoryToZip = directoryToZip;
        _zipToPath = _zipToPath;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try kernel32. Example below via the P/Invoke [LoadLibrary](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.loadlibrary) page.

```
[DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError=true)]
static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);
```